# find the equation of the tangent line to the curve 8/x^2+x+2 at x=2

Tags: calculus

help me please with this

find the equation of the tangent line to the curve 8/x^2+x+2 at x=2

I have tried nothing because i don't know what I'm doing

Comment: Hint: tangents have something to do with derivatives...

Comment: Don't you see this as cheating? Wouldn't it be better to ask a question that allows you to do this for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The slope of a curve at a certain point is the derivative evaluated at that point.
Let  $y=\frac{8}{x^2}+x+2$
Find its derivative;
$$y'=-\frac{16}{x^3}+1$$
Then evaluate $y'(2)$;

$$y'(2)=-\frac{16}{8}+1=-1$$

The equation of the tangent is $$y-y(2)=y'(x)(x-2)$$

Answer (score 0):

So you want the equation of a line, so you're going to need two things: A point and a slope.

Your function is $f(x)=\frac{8}{x^2}+x+2$.

To find the point, you just plug 2 into your original function. $f(2)=6$. So your point is $(2,6)$. Note that this point is on the graph of your function. You want the tangent line that passes through this point.

To find the slope of the tangent line AT that point, you need to plug $x=2$ into the derivative of $f$. The derivative of $f$ is $f'(x)=-\frac{16}{x^3}+1$. So $f'(2)=-1$.

Now that you have a point $(2,6)$ and slope -1, you use these to make the equation of a line.

$y-6=-1\cdot(x-2)$

and in y-intercept form, this is $y=-x+8$